# I want to know how to make a transform component a child of the root node

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code in the video that I am watching is perfect but I think it is because of the version of unity because he is using 2020.3.13f1 and I am using 2021.3.23f1 and I do not want to download another unity again first because of laziness and second because of space from my hard drive and third I already have 2 versions of unity so that I can download a third version and I don't know if the game I'm making will be horribly damaged by so many version changes and I'm afraid that will happen, so what do you have?

already tried with

```
transform.SetParent(transform.root);
```

but I think unity doesn't care about that line of code.
Here is the whole script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InventoryItem : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    Image img;
    public Transform ParentAffterDrag;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        img.raycastTarget = false;
        ParentAffterDrag = transform.parent;
        transform.SetParent(transform.root);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        img.raycastTarget = true;
        transform.SetParent(ParentAffterDrag);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working?  I assume you have looked at the documentation for SetParent?  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html
Sometimes the `worldPositionStays` flag can trip people up or cause unexpected results.

Comment: Also, `Input.mousePosition` is in Screen Pixel coordinates, not world coordinates like `Transform.position` is.  Perhaps that is intentional but just in case...